# Using jQuery to bind a drop down or radio button event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins, binding, drop-down-menu

Apparently this is very basic jQuery but im on a time crunch and I could use some help tweaking these tablesorter options.

This is a keyup function that queries a table, and it works great. I simply want to change the input type from a text feild to a drop down or radio buttons. What i have so far only works upon initial page load and then stops.

Keyup version:

```
$("#txt_topics").keyup(function() {
        $("#example-4").beautify("rebuild", { filter :
                    { 7 :$("#txt_topics").val() } });
    });
```

What ive got so far:

```
$("select").ready(function() {
             $("#example-4").beautify("rebuild", { filter :
                    { 7 :$("select").val() } });
    });

<select>
 <option value="2012">2012</option>
 <option value="2011">2011</option>
 <option value="2010">2010</option>
</select>
```

Thanks for any help any jQuery / javascript folks may have for me.

Comment: hiya, in case of drop down use $("select").change **or** $("#your_drop_down_id").change(.... hope this helps, cheers!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can bind the `change` or `focus`/`blur` events, depending on what exactly you're trying to do.  `change` will trigger any time the value is actually changed, `focus` and `blur` will fire when the box is selected and unselected, respectively.

```
$("select").change(function { ... });
```

Comment: Hey one more detail: would it be possible to save the chosen value in a URL in order to make a link to share the query results with someone else? Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This might help as well with demo:

http://jsfiddle.net/nEmPx/2/

If I may suggest read this on spare time will help you to be bit more clued up for Jquery events: http://api.jquery.com/change/

JQuerycode:

```
$("select").change(function(){
    alert('do whatever!');
     //$("#example-4").beautify("rebuild", { filter :
       //             { 7 :$("select").val() } });
});​
```

cheers,

PS: lolz Pizza comment above made me hungry now. :)

Comment: o wow jsFiddle is really helpful. is there a phpFiddle? or a cssFiddle?

Comment: :)  for css use the second text area on 1 row of jsfiddle it has css compatibility and for php fiddle see this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4902432/is-there-a-php-fiddle cheers!

Comment: Great!! Hey one more detail: would it be possible to save the chosen value in a URL in order to make a link to share the query results with someone else? Thanks

Comment: Yep it is! in jsfiddle you can do cntrl + s and share that saved url with anyone and you can fork mine or share the url I have got in my comments with anyone, hope this help, tc, cheers!